# Show the total price if number is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am trying to show in realtime the total price of the selected amount of a product. But i dom't get out with it, example: if you select 2 cards the price must be show in realtime : $10, and also that it counts the total amount and show the total price.

How can i fix this? This is my source:

```js
function updatePrice()
{
    
    var numSubTotal = parseInt($("#num-fruits option").filter(":selected").val());
    if (isNaN(numFruits)) numFruits = 0;
    
    $("#num-fruits").html(""+numFruits);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="652" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Product</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Product Price</strong></td>
    <td><strong>How much you want?</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Total Price</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="210">Fruit:</td>
    <td width="216">$ 10</td>
    <td width="204"><input name="number" type="number" id="number" value="5" onchange="updatePrice()"></td>
    <td width="204">$ 50 <span id="num-fruits">0</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Drinks:</td>
    <td>$ 25</td>
    <td><input name="number2" type="number" id="number2" value="25"></td>
    <td>$ 625</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cards:</td>
    <td>$ 5</td>
    <td><input type="number" name="number3" id="number3"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total price of all:</td>
    <td>$ 675</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

why isn't this code working?

Comment: Your `updatePrice` function is missing a closing brace.

Comment: And you don't have any `onchange` on your other input fields.

Comment: Ok, but can someone help me atleast with the missing closing brace please?

Comment: So many problems: The missing brace at the end of `updatePrice`. You set the variable `numSubTotal`, but then you try to use `numFruits`. You select `#num-fruits option`, but `#num-fruits` is a `<span>`, not a `<select>`, so it doesn't have any options.

Comment: And in jsfiddle, you have to use the `No Wrap` option to be able to call functions from `onchange` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML remove your `onchange` attribute, it's a bad practice.

Then, your Javascript is not taking care of all the fields (i.e. only Fruits), so replace it with this:

```
$("input").on("change", function () {
    var $input = $(this);
    var howMany = parseInt($input.val());
    var unitAmount = parseInt($input.parent().prev().text().replace("$",""));
    var total = howMany * unitAmount;
    $input.parent().next().text("$ " + total);
});
```

What this does is to detect when the "how much" input fields change and when that's the case, it retrieve how much a unit costs and multiplies by the number input in the "how much" field and writes the total in the last column.

Comment: Its not working: https://jsfiddle.net/0L2n8wdt/21/ because its not calculating the unity amount of fruits ( $10 ), so how can all the unit price so that the calculation will be like : unit_price * unitAmount

Comment: Make sure to replace ALL the Javascript, you don't need the `updatePrice` function and neither the `onchange` attributes in your HTML. Shall I edit your fiddle?

Comment: Wow Thank you very much, but how am i able to also show the total price?

Comment: But if i make the input type "text" the prices are not showing directly, but only when you click somewhere on the page ?: http://jsfiddle.net/0L2n8wdt/30/

Comment: Its showing : $NaN for total price, and also the text type for in input don't work ?

Comment: There you go http://jsfiddle.net/0L2n8wdt/32/